Getting a stable UID from a Blazor's Client Browser
My Goal: I want to have the Browser some how pass a static Identifier to the Blazor server so that I can have the Blazor application push the correct information to it.
Consider these units/browser-clients to be like a Kiosk where they are all pre-configured, they just have to go to their end locations.
But when the machine turns on, the kiosk mode in Windows will open Edge and run the web application.  I would like for the Client Browser to somehow submit some kind of message back to the Blazor web application that would include a unique identifier of some kind.  Such as a GUID, something that won't change when the browsers cookies are flushed.
I sort of understand CORS policies, I understand why they exist, what they are for.  I guess I don't have a lot of experience is setting the exceptions up, nor do I feel that I should spend my cycles on that.
What I tried to do is built a minimal API application that is deployed as a Windows Service that will output a GUID it writes once to a file.  I attempted to have the Blazor application make a local javascript call to http://localhost, but the browser (for good reason) blocked that and put it under the CORS policy.
I would like to do something similar, but I don't want to have this as part of the URL, I want it to be as part of the host headers berceuse that gets encrypted.
I also want to stay secure/future-proof and I would like to not need to do anything specific with the devices before I send them out.  What other tricks can I try here?  I have researched this a lot but haven't come up with anything else.
User authentication is also not an option, I want them to be able to simply boot up from day one with out any intervention from anyone and just start working.  Could there be some other 1 time set up authentication that would persist even after the user clears the cache, browser resets/updates, etc.?
Would something to do with Client certificates work?  I am using Cloudflare Zero Trust Tunnels to proxy my traffic.  (just an FYI)

My guess is to use some sort of security dongle (hardware or software) on the kiosk that you can use to authenticate the kiosk.
